# How to draw polygon with click listener on canvas using custom view?

Tags: android, canvas, onclicklistener, android-custom-view

Please give me any suggestions or need your help for set click listener of polygon, I have implemented below code for draw polygon using custom view.

```
public class CustomView extends View {

        Paint paint;
        List<ImagesAnnotationModel> annotationModelList;

        public CustomView(Context context, List<ImagesAnnotationModel> annotationModelList) {
            super(context);
            this.annotationModelList = annotationModelList;
            paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            paint.setColor(Color.RED);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
        }


        @Override
        protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);

            for (int i = 0; i < annotationModelList.size(); i++) {
                ImagesAnnotationModel imagesAnnotationModel = annotationModelList.get(i);
                try {
                    List<ImagesAnnotationModel.BodyJsonObject> model_data = imagesAnnotationModel.getBodyJsonObject();
                    Path wallpath = new Path();
                    wallpath.reset();
                    for (int j = 0; j < model_data.size(); j++) {
                        String xy = model_data.get(j).getXy();

                        String pos[] = xy.split(",");
                        if (j == 0) {
                            wallpath.moveTo(Float.parseFloat(pos[0]), Float.parseFloat(pos[1]));
                        } else {
                            wallpath.lineTo(Float.parseFloat(pos[0]), Float.parseFloat(pos[1]));
                        }
                    }
                    paint.setFlags(i);
                    
                    canvas.drawPath(wallpath, paint);

                    // canvas.drawCircle(x, y, 10, paint);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }

        public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
            Log.i("postion","f==>"+event.getFlags());


            return false;
        }

    }
```

I have added this custom view into relative layout and using lineTo() draw line and connect with each other so finally draw custom object on canvas.

Comment: so basically you need when user touch the view and when user stop touching by moving on other place of view you want to draw the line right ?

Comment: Hello @Ashvin,
No need click listener of object draw using line to, using forloop if two object draw then need click listener of both object.